# How can I destroy my session on nextAuth in NextJS 14?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I just started using Typscript,
I have a project that I developed with NextJS14. I am using NextAuth for authentication in this project.
When I write it with JavaScript, I do not get an error in this code, but I get an error on the typscript side.

My code is like this,

```
import { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
const Backend_URL = 'http://localhost:5031/api/';
export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',

      credentials: {
        userNameOrEmail: {
          label: 'userNameOrEmail',
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'jsmith',
        },
        password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials?.userNameOrEmail || !credentials?.password)
          return null;
        const res = await fetch(Backend_URL + 'Users/Login', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            accept: '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            userNameOrEmail: credentials.userNameOrEmail,
            password: credentials.password,
          }),
        });

        const user = await res.json();

        // Check if the response contains a message property
        if (user.message) {
          // Handle the error message here
          console.log(user.message);
          return null;
        }

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.accessToken = user?.token?.accessToken;
        token.expiration = user?.token?.expiration;
      }
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },

    async session({ token, session }) {
      session.user.name = token.userInfo.nameSurname;
      session.user.email = token.userInfo.email;
      session.user.userName = token.userInfo.userName;
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.expiration = new Date(token.expiration).toISOString();
      session.expires = new Date(token.expiration).toISOString();
      const currentDate = new Date();
      const expirationDate = new Date(token.expiration);

      if (currentDate < expirationDate) {
        console.log('time not over ');
        // Session is still valid, return the session as is
        return session;
      } else {
        console.log('time over ');
        // Session has expired, return undefined to log out the user
        // Ensure to include the 'expires' property with a valid ISODateString
        return null;
      }
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/Login',
    error: '/NextError',
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

The error I get is in the session section,
If the time has expired, I want the session to be null, that is, to redirect the user to the login page.

next-auth.d.ts file is this.

```
import "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    token: Token;
    userInfo: UserInfo;
    message?: string;
  }
  interface Session {
    user: {
      name: string;
      email: string;
      userName: string;
    };
    accessToken: string;
    expiration: string;
  }
}

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  /** Returned by the `jwt` callback  */
  interface JWT {
    accessToken: string;
    refresh_token: string;
    expiration: string;
    userInfo: UserInfo;
  }
}

interface Token {
  accessToken: string;
  expiration: string;
  refreshToken: string;
}

interface UserInfo {
  userName: string;
  email: string;
  nameSurname: string;
}
```

The required validity date for the token is sent to me by the backend. I want the token to be deleted when this date expires.

The Error;

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/kubil/OneDrive/Masaüstü/onionarch-fe/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2322",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type '({ token, session }: { session: Session; token: JWT; user: AdapterUser; } & { newSession: any; trigger: \"update\"; }) => Promise<Session | null>' is not assignable to type '(params: { session: Session; token: JWT; user: AdapterUser; } & { newSession: any; trigger: \"update\"; }) => Awaitable<Session | DefaultSession>'.\n  Type 'Promise<Session | null>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<Session | DefaultSession>'.\n    Type 'Promise<Session | null>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<Session | DefaultSession>'.\n      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.\n        Type '<TResult1 = Session | null, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: Session | null) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = Session | DefaultSession, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: Session | DefaultSession) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.\n          Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.\n            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.\n              Type 'Session | null' is not assignable to type 'Session | DefaultSession'.\n                Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Session | DefaultSession'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 55,
    "startColumn": 11,
    "endLineNumber": 55,
    "endColumn": 18
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Type 'Promise<Session | null>' is not assignable to type
> 'Awaitable<Session | DefaultSession>'

this is the error. As far as I know, since you have `jwt` token which contains an expiration timestamp `exp`,  `next-auth` automatically checks this exp claim to determine if the session is still valid or if it has expired.

But if you still want to return null, you should return this to make typescript happy:

```
if (currentDate < expirationDate) {
  console.log('time not over ');
  // Session is still valid, return the session as is
  return session;
} else {
  console.log('time over ');
  // Session has expired, return undefined to log out the user
  // Ensure to include the 'expires' property with a valid ISODateString
  return {
    user: {
      name: null,
      email: null,
      userName: null,
    },
    accessToken: null,
    expiration: null,
  }
  };
}
```

Comment: During this time, the session is not disrupted and the user can access every page. Can access pages without authorization.

Comment: if session is created, jwt is also created. jwt has `expiration time` stamp, so next-auth will already know when the session expired